# Karate-Runner : debug Mode & karate-config.js not read

Tags: karate, http-proxy

Impossible to load proxy settings from karate-config.js in debug mode

I set the proxy settings into the karate-config.js file and when i run Karate Test it is ok but when I switch to debug mode it seems that in that mode, the karate-config.js is not read and I am not able not complete my test in debug mode. I get an unknown host exception. If i add the proxy in the feature file, it works

Is there a specific setting to do ?
I work with VS Code & Karate-runner plugin